# Unable to read variable from require file

Tags: php, path, require

Why the main.php file cannot access the database table variable. I thought that in main.php I could query the database without reusing  `require_once './db.php'` When I require this file directly (not via Routes.php), the queries work. I'm not very experienced with PHP, and I suppose it works differently than I think.

**index.php**

```
require_once './db.php';

function autoLoad($file_name) {
  if(file_exists('./Classes/'.$file_name.'.php')) {
    require_once './Classes/'.$file_name.'.php';
  } else if(file_exists('./Controllers/'.$file_name.'.php')) {
    require_once './Controllers/'.$file_name.'.php';
  }
}
spl_autoload_register('autoLoad');
require_once './Routes.php';
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::set("/example/main.php", function() {
Main::createView("main");  <-- require main.php file
});
```

**main.php**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM items";
mysqli_query($conn, $query);   <-- Undefined variable...
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

$conn variable is from db.php, which I included inside index.php

Comment: Add `require_once './db.php';` to your main.php. If it was already included once, it won't again. So using this is safe. Make sure the path is correct.

Comment: When I added `require_once` to main.php file nothing happened, but after changed to `require`, variable `$conn` begins to be interpreted.